# How to create custom legends in Power bi?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I just need to move my legends in top left corner. But there is no option for that.

So is any way I can create maybe a table  with one column color shape and the other column the description?

Something like that:

[image]

And then just use it as Legends for the chart?

Comment: Power BI isn't great at custom formatting. It might be that the only way to do this is with a custom visual.

Comment: Oh   ok, Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your visual you have under the format tab a legend option. For example if you use a pie chart you can toggle the legend on or off. Also you can position the legend (top, top left, bottom, etc...).

The second way is to use a custom visual with your desired needs.

And the third way is, like you already stated, a table which acts as legend. Either you enter your legend text in a separate table manually or you use a query. For example a distinct count to get the unique values.